# Getting Date From user and Writing it in a URL

Tags: java, string, date, parsing, type-conversion

I want to get Starting and Ending Dates from user. The aim is getting the Date values between these days and editing the URL http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201805/07052018.xml

For example:
The user gives me the starting date, 07-08-2017 and the ending date 07-10-2017. I want to create a loop for all the days between these two and want this loop to create links like  http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/201708/07082017.xml, and so on.

```
    Date startDate;
            Date endDate;
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the starting date as MM/DD/YYYY");
            String a=input.next();

              System.out.println("Enter the ending date as MM/DD/YYYY");
              String c=input.next();

             SimpleDateFormat b= new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
             startDate= b.parse(a);

             endDate= b.parse(c);

            SimpleDateFormat d= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");

             String startDaate= d.format(startDate);

SimpleDateFormat e= new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
         String startDaate2= e.format(startDate);



System.out.println(startDate);
System.out.println(endDate);
        System.out.println(startDaate);
        System.out.println(startDaate2);
```

I tried this without the loop, for the starting date. And I get

Sun Jun 08 00:00:00 EEST 2014

Sat Jul 21 00:00:00 EEST 2018

062014 and 08062014

The edition for the loop when I get the Dates converted to String will be like

```
String s1="www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/"+startDaate+"/"+startDaate2+".xml";
```

And the loop will forward the firstDate1 Value(YYYYMM) and firstDate2 value(DDMMYYYY) to next day, or month. Therefore I need to forward the startDate 
 Date value to the next day.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?? Share with us.

Comment: I updated my answer . Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of `java.time` :

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

        ...

        String sDate;
        String eDate;

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
           System.out.print("Enter first Date (dd/MM/yyyy): ");
           sDate = scan.nextLine();
           System.out.print("Enter second Date (dd/MM/yyyy): ");
           eDate = scan.nextLine();

        }

        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        LocalDate dateStart = LocalDate.from(format.parse(sDate));
        LocalDate dateEnd = LocalDate.from(format.parse(eDate));
        while (!dateStart.isAfter(dateEnd)) {
            System.out.println(dateStart);
            dateStart = dateStart.plusDays(1);
        }
```

Or alternatively you can use [`joda time`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) api :

```
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.DurationFieldType;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

       ...

        String sDate = "07/08/2017";
        String eDate = "07/10/2017";

        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

        LocalDate dateStart = new LocalDate(format.parseLocalDate(sDate));
        LocalDate dateEnd = new LocalDate(format.parseLocalDate(eDate));

        int days = Days.daysBetween(dateStart, dateEnd).getDays();
        for (int i = 0; i < days; i++) {
            LocalDate d = dateStart.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i);
            System.out.println(d);
        }
```

**UPDATE :**

You have edited your question and according to my understanding you need three different date formats like below :

```
input date : dd/MM/yyyy
output date1 : yyyyMM
output date2 : ddMMyyyy
```

So I updated my answer as following :

```
String sDate = "07/08/2017";
String eDate = "07/10/2017";

DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter format2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
DateTimeFormatter format3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM");

LocalDate dateStart = LocalDate.from(LocalDate.parse(sDate, format1).withDayOfMonth(1)); // just getting the month and year from user input and start with first day of given month
LocalDate dateEnd = LocalDate.from(format1.parse(eDate));
while (!dateStart.isAfter(dateEnd)) {
    System.out.println("date1 : "+dateStart.format(format3) + " - date2: " + dateStart.format(format2));
    dateStart = dateStart.plusDays(1);
}
```

Output :

```
date1 : 201708 - date2: 01082017
date1 : 201708 - date2: 02082017
date1 : 201708 - date2: 03082017
date1 : 201708 - date2: 04082017
date1 : 201708 - date2: 05082017
date1 : 201708 - date2: 06082017

....
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks!